# How can I make a copy of all the values and worksheet style with a specific range?

Tags: excel, vba

Essentially I have an Excel sheet that refers to another sheet for all of its data. The Excel sheet is also formatted the way I like it.

Now I would like to create a copy of the Excel sheet with just the values and formatting, to trigger this I am using a button. The issue now is when making the copy, the button is  copied as well. How can I prevent the button from being copied?

Can I exclude it somehow?

**Here is my code so far:**

```
ActiveSheet.Copy
Cells.Copy
Range("A1:T40").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Even though I entered the range 'A1:T40' the button is still appearing (it is not in the range)

Comment: My dear boy that is why I am using a range. Is something wrong with the way I'm writing it? Is this not how properly copy relevant cells?

Comment: Is range `A1:T40` the range you want to copy? If so, state that. `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:T40").Copy`

Answer (score 1):

1. Qualify your objects with worksheets. I declared variables in case you have more code to work with after. You could also just use `With` block.
2. Only copy the range you care about, not the entire sheet
3. To paste values and formats, paste twice

---

```
Sub Test()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") '<-- Sheet to copy from
Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2") '<-- Sheet to paste on

ws1.Range("A1:T40").Copy

ws2.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
ws2.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats

End Sub
```

Comment: I would like to paste the values into a new sheet in a new workbook

Comment: Nowhere does your question say anything about a new book

Comment: If you don’t ask the right question , you will not get the right answer.

Comment: In my original code excel would open a new excel workbook. Try it out and you will see.

Comment: The code you shared is not enough to indicate a second book is present. All of that code can be for one book. Either way, you should be able to extend this as needed

Answer (score 0):

**The reason the button kept copying over when running the VBA script was because I needed to first run this:**

```
Application.CopyObjectsWithCells = False   <------
```

**At the end of the script I made sure to set *CopyObjectWithCells* to True**

This is the full script for anyone having the same issue:

```
Application.CopyObjectsWithCells = False
ActiveSheet.Copy
Range("A1:T40").Copy

Range("A1:T40").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.CopyObjectsWithCells = True
```